# Unable to create channel in hyperledger fabric

Tags: docker, docker-compose, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-fabric-ca

**I am able to create channel and do operations up to instantiate chain code in my local machine. When I work on AWS instance I am getting issue while creating channel**

[image]

Comment: In AWS we have public IP as well as local IP . When I am going with public IP I am facing issue. where as issue with local IP in AWS instance. Can any once tell what is this issue exactly

Comment: I am able to run block chain setup in new AWS instances successfully. I don't know what is the exact issue with old AWS instances